# MYSQL Insert into table's column based on column name

Tags: mysql

For some reason I am having difficulty wording this question but I will try my best. I've been searching for 2 days on and off now and haven't found a good solution to the issue.

I have a Table called InventoryNode;

```
 _________________________________________________
| InvID | ID | Slot | ItemID1 | ItemID2 | ItemID3 |
|-------|----|------|---------|---------|---------|
|   1   |  1 | Neck |   10    |   22    |   66    |
|   1   |  2 | Head |   26    |   23    |   56    |
|   1   |  3 | Leg  |   19    |   21    |   76    |
```

And another table called Inventory which stores the Node ID in each column

```
 _____________________________
| ID| Neck | Head | Leg | ... |
|---|------|------|-----|-----|
| 1 |   1  |  2   |  3  | 66  |
```

If there a way I can insert the node ID's into the Inventory table based off the InvID and populate all the columns with the correct name with the Node's ID?

Something like this?

```
INSERT INTO Inventory INNER JOIN InventoryNode ON 
(Inventory.ID = InventoryNode.InvID) WHERE Inventory.column_name =
 InventoryNode.Slot SET InventoryNode.InvID
```

Comment: The problem here is this schema which is a pretty flagrant violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). A proper relational structure would make this trivial.

Comment: Well I am aware that I am not that great at databases but this seemed like the best solution for my scenario. If you have a better way to store multiple items for a particular slot for a particular inventory, I would be open to suggestions. I  am not locked into this table design as it is just a personal project.

Comment: You've just discovered why it's not the best solution for your scenario even if initially it did seem promising. Break this out into a secondary table and make a proper one-to-many association. I'd even recommend breaking out slot as another table so you can add/remove slot-types in the future.